# Having Trouble Setting Up ESLint on IntelliJ IDEA (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components

I used npm init to create a package.json file on the root of my project, I then installed locally:

```
npm install eslint babel-eslint @lwc/eslint-plugin-lwc --save-dev
npm install eslint @salesforce/eslint-config-lwc --save-dev
```

and updated `.eslintrc.json` file under `force-app/main/default/lwc` with

```
{
  "extends": ["@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc/recommended"]
}
```

However, IntelliJ is not highlighting linting issues. If I open the same project in Visual Studio the LWC I am working does have the linting issues highlighted (VS Code comes with ESLint configured when you install the Salesforce Plugin)

If I do change I add any characters after "recommended" I get an ESLint Error:

> Error: Failed to load config "@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc/recommended2" to extend from.

so it is reading that `.eslintrc.json` file. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Is as if IntelliJ is not finding the rules inside

```
@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc/recommended
```

Comment: did you ever manager to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it executing: "eslint --init" from project root

when installation finish, i run "eslint ." from project root also

```
**PS C:\Users\-----\Desktop\salesforce\cursos\SFDX\steps\milansfdxproject> eslint --init**
? How would you like to use ESLint? To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style
? What type of modules does your project use? None of these
? Which framework does your project use? None of these
? Does your project use TypeScript? No
? Where does your code run? (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)Browser
? How would you like to define a style for your project? Use a popular style guide
? Which style guide do you want to follow? Standard (https://github.com/standard/standard)
? What format do you want your config file to be in? JavaScript
Checking peerDependencies of eslint-config-standard@latest
? The style guide "standard" requires eslint@>=6.2.2. You are currently using eslint@5.16.0.
  Do you want to upgrade? Yes
The config that you've selected requires the following dependencies:

eslint-config-standard@latest eslint@>=6.2.2 eslint-plugin-import@>=2.18.0 eslint-plugin-node@>=9.1.0 eslint-plugin-promise@>=4.2.1 eslint-plugin-standard@>=4.0.0
? Would you like to install them now with npm? Yes
Installing eslint-config-standard@latest, eslint@>=6.2.2, eslint-plugin-import@>=2.18.0, eslint-plugin-node@>=9.1.0, eslint-plugin-promise@>=4.2.1, eslint-plugin-standard@>=4.0.0
+ eslint-plugin-promise@4.2.1
+ eslint-plugin-node@11.1.0
+ eslint-plugin-standard@4.0.1
+ eslint@6.8.0
+ eslint-config-standard@14.1.1
+ eslint-plugin-import@2.20.2
added 75 packages from 36 contributors, removed 3 packages, updated 19 packages, moved 1 package and audited 538 packages in 33.021s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Successfully created .eslintrc.js file in C:\Users\-----\Desktop\salesforce\cursos\SFDX\steps\milansfdxproject
**PS C:\Users\-----\Desktop\salesforce\cursos\SFDX\steps\milansfdxproject> eslint .**

C:\Users\-----\Desktop\salesforce\cursos\SFDX\steps\milansfdxproject\force-app\main\default\aura\HelloWorld\HelloWorldController.js
  1:1   error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  2:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4                           indent
  2:5   error  Extra space after key 'myAction'                                       key-spacing
  2:24  error  Missing space before function parentheses                              space-before-function-paren
  4:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4                           indent

C:\Users\-----\Desktop\salesforce\cursos\SFDX\steps\milansfdxproject\force-app\main\default\aura\HelloWorld\HelloWorldHelper.js
  1:1   error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  2:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4                           indent
  2:5   error  Extra space after key 'helperMethod'                                   key-spacing
  2:28  error  Missing space before function parentheses                              space-before-function-paren
  4:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4                           indent

C:\Users\-----\Desktop\salesforce\cursos\SFDX\steps\milansfdxproject\force-app\main\default\aura\HelloWorld\HelloWorldRenderer.js
  1:1  error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  3:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 0                           indent

C:\Users\-----\Desktop\salesforce\cursos\SFDX\steps\milansfdxproject\force-app\main\default\lwc\helloWorld\helloWorld.js
  1:39  error  Extra semicolon                                semi
  3:60  error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

✖ 14 problems (14 errors, 0 warnings)
  11 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```